# How to make tests for gwt MVP activities and places project?

Tags: java, gwt, junit, mgwt

Does somebody know how to do tests for gwt application which is written with mvp, activities and places? I am reading out data from xml file and rendering them in a celllist.
I am using gwt 2.5 and eclipse.
i would be very thankful if somebody could show me an good tutorial for eclipse junit and gwt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activities and Places is a built-in framework for browser history management (not for MVP). Because you followed MVP model, you can use the advantage of MVP for painless GWT test. Please see [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture#testing) part of ["Large scale application development and MVP"](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture) article.

Answer (score 2):

We usually always refer to GWT unit tests before building up our unit tests.

GWT Source code is the place to look for Unit Tests written by GWT team.

Searching GWT Code - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/search?q=Places&origq=Places&btnG=Search+Trunk

[image]

Comment: i really doesnt understand what that is?
is gwt showing with this gwt-test-code only an example how to test places, placecontroller and so on?
or can we use it for import?

Comment: You need to use them as reference point for how to write up your test cases. In some cases if you are subclassing a GWT framework class you need to subclass these test cases as well.

Comment: ok that means that this is like a tutorial which shows how to write tests for places?

Comment: Yes and you can infer what to mock out, what not to test, what is already tested and how to organize your test cases.